# How to make tkinter delay a specific function without running another function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am aware of the .after method, but it requires a function to use.
I tried making a function that does nothing, but it just freezes the screen.
Is there a way to make it so it doens't modify the gui when doing .after? (I tried with a function that did, and it worked)

```
   def doNothing():
    return "nothing"


def init_timer(time=25):
    global minutes
    global onBreak
    minutes = 0
    onBreak = False
    while True:
        pomodoro()


def pomodoro():
    global pomodoros
    if pomodoros < 4:
        setTimer(25)
        while not(isTimerDone):
            print("Timer In Progress")
        setTimer(5)
        while not(isTimerDone):

        pomodoros += 1
    else:
        setTimer(30)




def timerDone():
    global onBreak
    global isTimerDone
    isTimerDone = True
    reminderTitle.config(text="The timer is done!")
    onBreak = not(onBreak)
    if onBreak:
        reminderTitle.config(text="Go on break!")
    else:
        reminderTitle.config(text="Get to work!")
    timer.config(text="Completed")
    playsound(f'{os.getcwd()}/Audio/notification.mp3')


def setTimer(mins=25):
    global isTimerDone
    isTimerDone = False
    timer.config(text="In Progress")
    window.after(mins * 60 * 1000, timerDone)
```

Comment: `.after` method takes milliseconds as an argument not minutes, also it just schedules a function to run, doesn't make the function non-blocking, maybe try using `threading`, anyways, what are you trying to achieve? also provide a [mre]

Comment: I am trying to create a pomodoro timer with tkinter, but it freezes everything. I cannot figure out why

Comment: because you use `while` loops, you can't use them in the same thread with `tkinter` without blocking the `.mainloop`, either use another thread or use `.after` "loops" properly, you can't use `while`, also there are multiple questions on this site that ask how to create a timer, you need to look at those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when you use while function . So, in order to make your program work properly you have to use `.after` only , not inside a while function .Here is an example that you could base on to improve your program :
import tkinter as tk

```
root = tk.Tk()
clock = tk.Label(root)

k = 0

def timing(time):
    '''time in minutes'''
    global k
    k = time
    clock.configure(text = 'you still have : ' + str(time) + ' minutes')
    def change_value():
        global k
        if k >  0:
            k = k-1
            clock.configure(text = 'you still have : ' + str(k)+' minutes')
            root.after(60000,change_value)
        else : 
            clock.configure(text = "it's over")
  
    
    root.after(60000,change_value)


timing(5)

clock.pack()
root.mainloop()
```